# How to add smiley in WP7 using RichTextBox?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can anyone tell is there any way to add smiley in RichTextBox. If possible kindly provide link or code to proceed

Comment: Would this help? http://www.1800pocketpc.com/smilies-windows-phone-mango/21335/

Comment: The link you provided list the smiley's that are available in wp7 what i need is code to implement this smiley in app. eg if user types :) then its graphical smiley should be displayed in RichTextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll depend on what smiley you want to add but there are lots of options.
For instance:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <Paragraph>;)</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>☺</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>&#x236a;</Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: need '☺' smiley. When user types ;) in textbox and hit enter then ☺ should appear in RichTextBox. How to do that i gave InputScopeNameValue.Chat as inputscope for textbox still i am getting only ;). how to get ☺

Comment: @Lydia you'll have to do the substitution yourself. Maybe on the TextChanged event.

Comment: Logic i should implement i agree what i want is how to get ☺. I tried all combination in keyboard but i was unable to get ☺ symbol :(